# Youtube Player APi android enable context menu

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, contextmenu

Hello All please help me to get out with a solution. My problem is i want to enable context menu three dots on youtube player Fragment. but i'm unable to find any method for this. 
Thanks in advance.

youTubePlayerFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(maenu, inflater);

I'm using above method but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts little bit confusing what do you want. But if you want to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` method inside the fragment you don't see anything on toolbar because you have to override `onCreate` method and put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside `onCreate` method. To override `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I want three dot icon as in YouTube top right on the you tube api. I'm using YouTube view for playing the videos .

Comment: Can you post some url to show me what do you actually want?

Comment: Please have a look on this screen.     https://www.dropbox.com/s/8896h13c1ito2hp/Screenshot_2017-03-26-19-42-36-673_com.google.android.youtube.png?dl=0. Three dots on top right corner

Comment: How did you created your menu xml? I'm not sure do you have to create menu manualy or it can be found inside API. Did you try with `setPlayerStyle` and use `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT` according to documentation that should enable all interactive controls. So maybe that including thing that you want.

Comment: Yes I know but I want only three dots icon nothing else. Anyways . Thanks

Comment: Than create it in menu file and try to add it. You can use android built in or download from google resources page: https://material.io/icons/#ic_more_vert